# backBarButtonItem with popViewController and swipe

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, ios7

My App logic is like that: VCA => VCB, and there is a scroll view in VCB with swipe left and right function. Some code help to understand structure, in VCB:

```
self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
self.scrollView.directionalLockEnabled = YES;
self.scrollView.contentSize =CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.scrollView.frame) * numberPages, CGRectGetHeight(self.scrollView.frame));
```

so what I want is list some pages horizontally and swipe to left and right to navigate. Each page has it own view controller(child view controller of VCB) and I add them like that:

```
if (controller.view.superview == nil)
{
    [self addChildViewController:controller];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:controller.view];
    [controller didMoveToParentViewController:self];               
}
```

So far it works fine for iOS 6. I can swipe to change page. All function inside each page also works fine.

Then the problem comes with iOS 7's new feature, swipe to right to automatically call `popViewControllerAnimated:`, same effect like click go back button. To solve the conflict, I disable the interactivePopGestureRecognizer: `self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;` 
and it works ok, no force to pop back when I just want to swipe change the page.

Now the real problem. I set a back button(backBarButtonItem) on navigation bar. Every time I use that button pop from VCB back to VCA and current page is not the first page (that means there is at least one page on the left side), the pop animation is like first change page to the left side one, then immediately show VCA without any animation.

So any solution? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it is hard to determine the problem without any piece of your code.

And secondly, why won't you create the button yourself, and add a target to it, a function that'll dismiss / pop the view controller?

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. I edit question with some code and more explanation.

Comment: And about using custom back button, I think for iOS 7, the back button won't be in the right spots because OS leave some place for that "<" arrow. So is there some way to directly solve the problem? Thanks again.

Comment: When this gap "happens", you did it programmatically or storyboard/xib ?

Comment: Thanks, looks like the gap not happen at all. Maybe only for the test version. Sorry for long time to reply